# MySQL Connector/Net Trace

Tags: mysql, trace

Does anyone know a way to enabled Tracing using a TraceListener for the MySQL Connector/net I'd like it to log the SQL Queries that are actually run against the DB, i.e. see the SQL with the parameter values substituted in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use slow_query_log paramter for inspecting queries that come to your server as of mysql 5.1.21. Just set slow_query_log = 0 and use the option --log-slow-queries[=file_name]. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I only know of a program for this: Jet Profiler for MySQL (not free)

[www.jetprofiler.com/](http://www.jetprofiler.com/)